# Why GRUB menu does not show?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, boot-repair, grubrescue

So, I've installed UBUNTU 20.04 recently, and there is no way to show the GRUB menu... I've tried reinstalling ubuntu, I've tried Boot-Repair tool on live ubuntu, I've changed all the settings in BIOS, "Secure Boot" is off, "Quick Boot" is off, Windows Boot Manager is the last option in the boot order, I've disabled Bitlocker, ubuntu was installed on UEFI mode, and I don't know what to do next... I think I've tried almost everything

Currently, I have Windows 11 installed on a Lenovo ThinkPad E15.
When I start the computer it shows a message about ThinkVantage active protection sensor, but I don't know what this is. And, I don't know how to disable it.

Comment: Can you boot into Ubuntu?

Comment: No, it boots directly to Windows11

Comment: Try pressing the F8 key when the Windows logo pops up. This should put you into the Windows boot menu. If you have set Windows as the primary OS, it will automatically boot Windows.

Comment: Have you updated UEFI & SSD firmware? It looks like active protection is for hard drive protection if tilted or dropped. Do you have this setting which some Lenovo systems have. The Device Guard BIOS setting locks down the boot order to internal HDD/SSD only. Lenovo Thinkpad E531 - turn off locked boot order setting in UEFI
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2255746

Comment: Already tried turning off locked boot order, didnt work. I will try that again, as Im trying boot/repair again and it taking much longer to finish. Oh and Ubuntu is not showing on boot order

Comment: I dont think ive updated UEFI & SSD